# Помогите пожалуйста найти ошибку в коде с циклом for

Tags: python, for

Нам в школе задали задачу, я решал как сказала учительница, но программа так не работает, пытался переделать по своему, получилось только в порядке возрастания. Вот задача:
По данному натуральному n ≤ 9 выведите возрастающую лесенку из n ступенек, последняя ступенька состоит из чисел от i до 1 через пробел.

```
n=int(input('Введите число '))
for i in range(1, n+2):
  for i in range(i, 1):
        print(i, end=' ')
  print('\n')
```

```
7

7 6

7 6 5

7 6 5 4  

7 6 5 4 3

7 6 5 4 3 2

7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

должен быть такой результат

Comment: У вас тут условие никогда не выполняется, т.к. по условию будет до 1: `for i in range(i, 1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо просто тщательно всё посчитать откуда и докуда перечислять. И не забыть шаг указать в `range` для цикла, у которого шаг отличается от стандартного шага 1:

```
n=int(input('Введите число '))
for i in range(1, n+1):
  for j in range(n, n-i, -1):
        print(j, end=' ')
  print('\n')
```

Вывод:

```
Введите число 7
7 

7 6 

7 6 5 

7 6 5 4 

7 6 5 4 3 

7 6 5 4 3 2 

7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Подправил второй цикл:

```
n = 5
for i in range(1, n+2):
    for j in range(i):
        print(j, end=' ')
    print()
```

Результат:

```
0 
0 1 
0 1 2 
0 1 2 3 
0 1 2 3 4 
0 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: @WaP1, комментарии плохо подходят для кода, если есть уточнения, то добавьте их в вопрос :) Если мой ответ вам помог, то примите его ;)

Comment: я добавил в вопрос уточнение, спасибо